# How to see Windows services that depend on a service with Python?

Tags: python, windows, service, process, dependencies

Using the Windows Services console, you can see which services depend on a service under Properties > Dependencies > "The following system components depend on this service:". How you can you get the same information with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same function as in the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254787/how-to-see-a-windows-service-dependencies-with-python) question can be used. Basically, use subprocess.check_output() to query sc with EnumDepend parameter:

```
dependencies = subprocess.check_output(["sc", "EnumDepend", service,"4000"],
                                       universal_newlines=True)
```